# Pass object through function

Tags: php, function, object, parameters

I am trying to pass a PHP object as parameter trough a function but I get the following errors:

**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object**

**Call to a member function create() on a non-object**

```
$mollie = new Mollie_API_Client;
$mollie->setApiKey("0000");   

add_action( 'init', 'gtp_mollie_payment_submit' );
function gtp_mollie_payment_submit( $mollie ) {

    if( isset( $_POST['checkout_submit'] ) ) {

        $payment = $mollie->payments->create(array(
            "amount"        => 10.00,
            "description"   => "My first API payment",
            "redirectUrl"   => "https://webshop.example.org/order/12345/",
            "method"        => Mollie_API_Object_Method::IDEAL,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: @George This is a Wordpress function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Comment: Your comment appears to claim that you are worried that $mollie is not an object. That is not the error. The error is that $mollie->payments is not an object. Are you certain that it is?

Comment: @kainaw Yes I'm sure that it is.

Comment: I'm having the _exact_ same error with Mollie. Did you solve this @Robbert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with an object oriented way:

```
class MyMollieGateway {
   private $mollie;

   function __construct() {
       $this->mollie = new Mollie_API_Client;
       $this->mollie->setApiKey( "0000" );

       add_action( "init", array( $this, "createPayment" ) );
   }

   function createPayment() {
       if( isset( $_POST['checkout_submit'] ) ) {
            $payment = $mollie->payments->create(array(
                "amount"        => 10.00,
                "description"   => "My first API payment",
                "redirectUrl"   => "https://webshop.example.org/order/12345/",
                "method"        => Mollie_API_Object_Method::IDEAL,
            ));
        }
    }
}

$_mollie = new MyMollieGateway;
```